# Find and hide text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

This, I thought, was a very simple query, but I seem to be getting lost in the find/hide code.

To simplify:

I may have something like this `<h1 class="begin-page"> TEST AREA</h1>`

I want to find the text "**TEST AREA**" and hide it.

How can I accomplish that via jquery?

Thank you.

Comment: possible, but could be pretty intensive depending on the size of the page. would be better if you knew the type/class/id of the container so it could be narrowed down.

Comment: also, what do you mean by hiding? do you want to hide the element it is within? or just remove that specific text from that element?

Comment: SMerny - in this case, just the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('h1.begin-page').html($('h1.begin-page').html().replace("TEST AREA", ""));
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure why - it works for me. Try breaking it up to see what your problem is: var headerText = $('h1.begin-page').html(); then a separate $('h1.begin-page').html(headerText.replace("TEST AREA", ""));

Answer (score 3):

```
$('h1:contains("TEST AREA")').html('');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/W5Av8/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('h1.begin-page')  // target the h1 element with class 'begin-page'
      .hide();          // hide it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

copy the code-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hb").click(function(){
    $("h1.begin-page").hide();
  });
});
</script>
    <p id="hb">hide</p>
    <h1 class="begin-page"> TEST AREA</h1>
```

or if you want you can hide and show just in a function-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hb").click(function(){
    $("h1.begin-page").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
    <p id="hb">[hide/show]</p>
    <h1 class="begin-page"> TEST AREA</h1>
```

code without extras-

```
      $(function(){
        $("h1.begin-page") // find the text
.hide(); // hide it
      });
```

from - http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp